# Why I can't find existing shader by script?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, shader

In editor script :

```
Material material = new Material(Shader.Find("Universal Render Pipieline/Lit"));
```

but material is null since it didn't find the "Universal Render Pipieline/Lit"
but in the editor it exist.

This is a screenshot of a material I created using this shader. I want to create this material in the script :

[image: Shader]

If the shader is exist in the editor why the script can't find it ?

I created a new Dissolve graph and with that installed some packages and created a new shader file name : NewShaderVariants

Inside this shade there is also this :

[image: Shader]

I don't see any typo problem.

[image: pipline asset]

[image: Another asset]

Comment: There is a typo in your string. This could be the error.

Comment: Universal Render Pipieline/Lit  not Pipeline

Comment: @Frenchy Still getting the null error

Comment: @MaxPlay still getting the null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change "Universal Render Pipieline/Lit" to "Universal Render Pipeline/Lit"